# looping through variables during runtime

Tags: vb.net

is there a way to loop through a set of defined variables during runtime without having to write a new line of code to handle each variable
for example the following code of a console application:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a!, b#, c%, d&, s$

        Console.WriteLine("a " & VarType(a).ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("b " & VarType(b).ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("c " & VarType(c).ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("d " & VarType(d).ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("s " & VarType(s).ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

a dummy code would be something like this :

```
for each Var in DefinedVariables 
'Do Something To the variable
next
```

Comment: You could add those variables to a collection and loop through that?

Comment: What you're looking for is called an array, or a list, or a collection, etc.

Comment: Check out `MethodBody.LocalVariables` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.localvariables(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MethodBody.LocalVariables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.localvariables(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve local variables declared within a method body as a list of [LocalVariableInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instances.  Unfortunately you only have access to them via index, as the name is not stored. You basically get the variable type, the ordinal it was declared at, and whether or not it is pinned. Optimization may even reorder variables or completely eliminate them.

```
Dim mi As MethodInfo =  GetType(Example).GetMethod("MethodBodyExample")
Dim mb As MethodBody = mi.GetMethodBody()
Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Method: {0}", mi)

' Display the general information included in the 
' MethodBody object.
Console.WriteLine("    Local variables are initialized: {0}",  mb.InitLocals)
Console.WriteLine("    Maximum number of items on the operand stack: {0}",   mb.MaxStackSize)

' Display information about the local variables in the
' method body.
Console.WriteLine()
For Each lvi As LocalVariableInfo In mb.LocalVariables
    Console.WriteLine("Local variable: {0}", lvi)
Next
```

Comment: I don't know how much use you will get out of it, as there isn't much data preserved after compilation.  You basically get the variable type, the ordinal it was declared at, and whether or not it is pinned.  Optimization may even reorder variables or completely eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, use a collection. For example

```
    Dim letters As New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c", "d"}

    For Each letter In letters
        Console.WriteLine(letter)
    Next
```

Edit:

```
    Dim a As String = "a"
    Dim b As String = "b"
    Dim c As String = "c"
    Dim d As String = "d"
    Dim e As Integer = 123

    Dim variables As New List(Of Object) From {a, b, c, d, e}

    For Each value In variables
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the array and collections, but lets say during the runtime there are many defined variables with various scopes, i just want to go through all these variables to know something about them .... defining a list of strings is not what im looking for here ... thanks

Comment: Can't you add the variables to a collection? Updated answer to reflect

Comment: it could work , but imagine having multiple procedures and each procedure  having its own variables and some public/private variables which can be seen across the module .... how do you loop through those variable which are accessible during a defined run-time point ? my code above was a simple example but i should have elaborated on it . thanks again for the help